# Expand and collapse in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table which is being generated from server side and it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kz55x/).

Now the requirement is to hide all the column of Category B, remove duplicate rows for Category A and show entries of corresponding entries of Category B in expand-collapse way. Each `A1 Name` Column cell will have a expand button and when it is clicked the entries of B columns of that row will be shown below that.

I'm able to hide B category and remove duplicate rows by

```
var hide_duplicate_row = function () {
            var seen = {};
            $('td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
                var txt = $(this).text();
                if (seen[txt])
                    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
                else
                    seen[txt] = true;
            });
        };


var show_only_head = function(){
$('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').hide();
$('td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
}

hide_duplicate_row();
show_only_head();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/3/

but I'm stuck with the expand collapse part, how do I populate the B category's row data in this way? Any input on this will be appreciated, thanks.

Full table:

[image]

Desired table:

[image]

Comment: How about using `rowspan`?

Comment: @Chankey could you please confirm that you must keep the server generated code and you need to generate the desired table using jQuery only?

Comment: @Minister: Yes, you are right. Server generated code must be kept and I have to use only client side solution, so yes either jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the plan for this:

Goes through the table rows one by one:

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
```

On each row get the content you need:

```
var cell_3 = $("td:nth-child(3)", this).html(); // a3
var cell_4 = $("td:nth-child(4)", this).html(); // a4
```

While you are still processing the current row modify the A1 column like this:

```
$( "td:nth-child(1)", this ).append( '<div class="toggle">' + cell_3 + ' - ' + cell_4 + '</div>' );
```

Now you should have a newly generated DIV in each A1 column. You'll need to assign a toggle functionality on 'click' event and you should be done. The END.

It seems you are developing using jQuery and this is the reason to explain you the idea, not giving you the exact code. :-)

**EDIT 1**:

Here is the final code, according to the few specific requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/26/ and some formatting: http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/30/

Comment: Thanks, check [what I tried by your logic](http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/8/). I'm getting error in line 32. Please let me know how can I select the `span` tag inside `td`?

Comment: OK, let's first check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/9/ - I've modified the HTML as it seemed to me that there are missing 'tr' around the 'th' elements. Is this the correct HTML or we MUST use your (without 'th')?

Comment: Oh yes yours is correct. BTW I got how to select that span, I used `$( this ).find( 'span' ).removeClass(className);`. I'll show you full solution in some minutes.

Comment: OK, then the next question: did you notice the toggle functionality: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ - check the example: $( "#clickme" ).click(function()

Comment: On the span selector - I would recommend you use: $(".first_td span").click(function() ...

Comment: Done. Now just one thing remaining, the third row should show 2 entries, it's showing only 1 at this moment. http://jsfiddle.net/ME3kG/15/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45618/discussion-between-minister-and-chankey-pathak)

Answer (score 0):

Add a div in your td which is hidden onload and display it on click event